# How to toggle one of multiple y axis on chart.js

Tags: angular, chart.js

What I've already achieve is displaying data on graph with **multiple y axis** displayed on the left from the graph like this

[image]

What's more if you click at the top on toggle 'SeriesA', 'SeriesB', 'SeriesC' this data hide / show, so I also would like to **hide / show this additional y axis simultaneously.**

Now only data on graph are hidden.
Is there any chart option to do this?

This is my code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng2-charts-hjw4xn?file=app%2Fline-chart.component.ts

**UPDATE 1:**

iot obtain possibility of switching on and off axis and its corresponding y axis this code should be added:

```
private chart: Chart;

public chartOptions: any = {
    legend: {
      onClick: this.chartSwitcher,
    }
}

private chartSwitcher(e, legendItem) {
   let index = legendItem.datasetIndex;
   let alreadyHidden = this.chart.getDatasetMeta(index).hidden;
   if (!alreadyHidden) {
      this.chart.getDatasetMeta(index).hidden = true;
      this.chart.options.scales.yAxes[index].display = false;
   } else {
      this.chart.getDatasetMeta(index).hidden = false;
      this.chart.options.scales.yAxes[index].display = true;
   }
   this.chart.update();   
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done the cleanest using the [Plugin Core API](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api). The API offers a range of hooks that may be used for performing custom code.

You could use the `beforeLayout` hook as shown below. The function iterates over the datasets and sets the `yAxes.display` option depending whether the corresponding `dataset` is hidden or not.

```
chartPlugins = [{
  beforeLayout: chart => chart.data.datasets.forEach((ds, i) => chart.config.options.scales.yAxes[i].display = !chart.getDatasetMeta(i).hidden)
}];
```

The plugins need to be defined on the `canvas` as follows:

```
<canvas baseChart 
  ...
  [plugins]="chartPlugins">
</canvas>
```

Please take a look at the following [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng2-charts-toggle-axis-visibility?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: `uminder` - thanks a lot for this simple and nice solution. One question inside forEach you passed two elements (ds, i)  i - stands for index of element, but what stands for ds?

Comment: ds stands for the dataset

Comment: Thanks, probably you may know which method from this `Plugin Core API` I have to use when I want to update my chart based on some values typed by user, eg. show only those values which on the X axis has specified values eg `from B to E`

Comment: To show only specific values, there's no need to use the `Plugin Core API`. You can change the data in the dataset upon user action and update the chart afterwards.

Comment: Button update may be outside the `canvas` tag? I still don't know how to pass new datalist to dataset,  
chartDatasets: Array<any> = [
    {data: this.dataList, label: 'Data1, yAxisID: 'data1'},
] 
Have I to add onclick method to this?

Comment: Since this is a new issue, please post a new question and possibly provide the full code you already have. This makes it easier for me or someone else to come up with a viable solution to your problem.

Comment: Could anyone give me some advice how can I swap this method, because on init I would like to have nothing (no curves, no y axis), after click on appropriate label -> show curve and its corresponding y axis?